# Is there an API to fetch similar terms from ( Elsevier ) EMBASE EMTREE?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, medical

I need to fetch the similar meaning terms for a given input medical term at run time. The source database is EMTREE ( Elsevier EMBASE Thesaurus for medical terms ). But on the Elsevier Developer portal,
( https://dev.elsevier.com/  ), there is no mention of EMTREE, though it mentions many other APIs for accessing different Elsevier products.

P.S. I do have EMBASE login & Elsevier API Key generated.